# How to send users to Home Activity who already setup their Profile details?? in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I am working on an application where I have created a user login system with a phone number. When the user login to the first time the User will go to Phone Activity then OTP Activity and then Setup Profile Activity to edit the name and other details and then to the Home Activity. So I want that when the already registered user login again. Then that user should skip the profile setup activity, User should move to the Home Activity directly after the OTP activity. I am using the firebase phone method to log in. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option that you have is to store a boolean value called `profileCompleted` in [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) or in the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database). Each time the user opens the app, you have to check against this value and take action accordingly. In Firestore, this field can be added inside the user object like this:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- users (collection)
       |
       --- $uid (document)
            |
            --- profileCompleted: true
            |
            --- //other fields
```

Local storage like SharedPreferences isn't a recommended option in this case, because it doesn't persist across application uninstalls.

Comment: You're very welcome, Vivek.

Comment: You are always great support for me sir. I am about to finish my app and the large part I have completed because of your amazing support, Sir. Thank You So Much.